# Collapse multiple data targets using Bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have three buttons that expand/collapse three divs, using Bootstrap. However, if I click on two different buttons in succession I get two divs expanded one after the other. Is it possible that before one div is expanded all others are collapsed so that only one div at a time can be visible?

Right now, if I had clicked on button 1 to expand Div1, I have to click on the button 1 again to collapse Div1 before I can click on button 2; otherwise contents of Div1 and Div2 both are displayed.

This is what I have:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <button class="btn btn-lg open-group" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Div1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Div1">Div1 Button<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <button class="btn btn-lg open-group" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Div2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Div2">Div2 Button<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <button class="btn btn-lg open-group" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Div3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Div3">Div3 Button<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="collapse" id="Div1">Content of Div1 here </div>
<div class="collapse" id="Div2">Content of Div2 here </div>
<div class="collapse" id="Div3">Content of Div3 here </div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for an "accordion"? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to set a parent using `data-parent="#parentdiv"` to the `toggle` then have the class `panel` to contain all toggleddivs.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="parentdiv"class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
  <div class="panel">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <button class="btn btn-lg open-group" type="button" data-parent="#parentdiv"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Div1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Div1">Div1 Button<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <button class="btn btn-lg open-group" type="button" data-parent="#parentdiv" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Div2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Div2">Div2 Button<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <button class="btn btn-lg open-group"data-parent="#parentdiv" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Div3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Div3">Div3 Button<span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
    </div>


<div class="collapse" id="Div1">Content of Div1 here </div>
<div class="collapse" id="Div2">Content of Div2 here </div>
<div class="collapse" id="Div3">Content of Div3 here </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks; it works. For me it flickers a bit when one div is replaced by another but I will try to work it out. Marked it as answer.